# $\mathbb C$ isomorphism to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ under multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

How can I show, that $(\mathbb C,\cdot)$ is not isomorphic to  $(\mathbb{R},\cdot) \times  (\mathbb{R},\cdot)$ under multiplication?
I tried to point out that $f(1) = 1$, then pair $(1,1) \rightarrow 1 + 0i$, but then I god stuck. 
I know these semigroups are isomorph under addition, but any reasonable mapping seems not to be even homomorphism (due to fact, that $(a + bi)(c + di) \neq a+c + i(b+d)$.

Edit: Sorry, I assumed those were groups.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ is a field, but $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ isn't even a domain.

Comment: Former is a field, latter is not.

Comment: If by $(\mathbb{C},.)$ and $(\mathbb{R}, .)$ you mean the groups comprising the non-zero elements of the fields $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ under multiplication, then ask yourself how many solutions the equation $x^4 = 1$ has.

Comment: @RobArthan I do not think this works. Yet $x^2 = -1$ would.

Comment: @quid: sorry, I deleted my comments by mistake. Counting solutions to $x^2 = 1$ solves the problem. It doesn't quite make sense to count solutions to $x^2 = -1$, because $-1$ is not definable just using the multiplicative structure.

Comment: @RobArthan: yes that is simpler. For $-1$ not being definable, I am not sure I follow,  $(-1,-1)$ is a specific element of $\mathbb{R}^2$. But it is admittedly not the most natural thing.

Comment: I understand that if I'd consider a ring $(\mathbb C,.,+)$ then I get field and $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ is not even a domain, but since I work only with groups is this proper argumentation?

Comment: @quid: what I mean is that you would need to characterize $-1$ just using the multiplicative group structure in order to use it in a proof that the two multiplicative groups are not isomorphic.

Comment: @Ajey: sorry that I deleted some comments by mistake, but if you follow my suggestion of counting solutions to $x^2 = 1$ you should be able to see that the two multiplicative groups are not isomorphic.

Comment: Let me apologize, I considered $(\mathbb C,.)$ and $(\mathbb R,.)$ as groups yet they obviously are only semigroups.

Comment: @RobArthan I understood this but I disagree with it. The real numbers (with multiplication) are the set of real numbers plus some structure. Even without any structure specified I can talk about specific elements of the real numbers. Furthermore, the element $-1$ in the real numbers is even 'definable' just using multiplication. It is the element other then the identity that is a solution of $x^2=1$.

Comment: @quid: yes, but that definition doesn't work in $\mathbb{R}_{\times}^2$ which has $3$ solutions to $x^2 = 1$ other than the identity element $1 = (1, 1)$.

Comment: @RobArthan once has  $-1$ in $\mathbb{R}$ one can consider $(-1,-1)$ in the Cartesian product. (If you do not consider this type of reasoning as valid, how do you establish the number of solutions to the equation you propose.)

Comment: @quid: my point is that you can talk about solutions to the equation $x^2 = 1$ in the language of group theory (written multiplicatively) but not $-1$.

Comment: @RobArthan this is  correct, but not quite relevant for the problem at hand as we are considering a structure on a  *specific* set, which is my point. (For example $\mathbb{R}$ contains $\pi$ and $e $, and $3.5 + \pi^2 $ and $-1$, thus in the context of *this* problem we can wonder what element could be the preimage under an isomorphism of $(3.5 + \pi^2, -234) $.)

Comment: @quid: the point is that saying "$-1$" doesn't specify an element in $\mathbb{R}_{\times}^2$, but "solution of $x^2 = 1$" does specify a subset of that group, which happens to have $4$ elements, unlike the set specified by the same phrase in $\mathbb{C}_{\times}$ which only has $2$.

Comment: @RobArthan  but  $(-1,-1)$ does, and the $-1$ is  nothing but a (perhaps sloppy)   shorthand for this.

Comment: @quid: how do you define $(-1 , -1)$ as an element of $\mathbb{R}_{\times}^2$ using only the multiplicative group operations? That is what you need to do in an argument of the kind we need here to show that this group is not isomorphic to some other group.

Comment: @RobArthan there is *no need* to define it in this way. There is a) a particular element of the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$,  commonly denoted $-1$, and thus b) there is the element $(-1,-1)$ in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. If you disagree please make precise with which part you disagree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20637/discussion-between-rob-arthan-and-quid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $(\mathbb{C}, \cdot)$ and $(\mathbb{R}, \cdot)^2$ are not isomorphic as semigroups, observe that both semigroups have a (necessarily unique) annihilator, an element $a$ such that $ax = a$ for any $x$. Both semigroups have a unique element $e$ such that $ex = x$ for any $x \not= a$ (in fact the elements other than $a$ form a subsemigroup that is actually a group). The equation $x^2 = e$ has 2 solutions in $(\mathbb{C}, \cdot)$ but 4 solutions in $(\mathbb{R}, \cdot)^2$. Since we can define $a$ and $e$ using only the semigroup operation, the two semigroups cannot be isomorphic.

Answer (score 4):

In the semigroup $(\mathbb{C}, \cdot)$ each element admits a square-root, that is for each $a \in \mathbb{C}$ there is an $x$ such that $x^2 = a$.

Suppose there is an isomorphism $f$, that is a bijective map such that $f(cd)=f(c)f(d)$ for all $c,d$. Let $a = f^{-1} ((-1,-1))$ and let $x$ be a squaroot of $a$. Let $f(x)= (b_1,b_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then, on the one hand $f(a) = (-1,-1)$, yet on the other hand $f(a) = f(x^2) = f(x)^2 = (b_1,b_2)^2 = (b_1^2, b_2^2)$.

This would yield $b_1^2 = -1 $ and $b_2^2 = -1 $ in the real numbers, which is not possible. This contradiction shows that there is no isomorphism.